# Is it possible to insert date automatically in one cell in MS excel 2007

Tags: timestamp, keyboard-shortcuts, excel-2007, spreadsheet

I have one excel document with two columns. 
i only add text in one column on daily basis and i want that on second column the current date and time automatically gets added.

That field can be hidden as well and i can get when i wanted but want the date time when i added in that row

Is it possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `TODAY()` or `NOW()` function? It will return the today's date.  Be warned that **tomorrow** if you open the spreadsheet the cell will show tomorrow's date. So you would need to have a macro copy and paste values only into the date cell.

I think the other thing you could do, is to use keyboard shortcuts `CTRL + ;` or `CTRL + :` to insert current date and time in the active cell. Since this places the value, you don’t need to worry if the date or time changes. But this is manual, and may or may not be what you are after.

Comment: CTRL + ; is a good one to me. It works in Google spreadsheets as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:IV")) Is Nothing Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 1) = MonthName(Month(Date))
    Cells(Target.Row, 2) = Date
End If
End Sub
```